# How to print the alphabet with the 'write' function?

Tags: c

I have to print the alphabet using the `write()` function. I can not use `printf()` to see the output.

I have this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char ft_print_alphabet(char);

int main()
{
    char ch;

    for(ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
        write(1, %ch, 26);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I have tried to do this but I do not understand the `write()` function at all.

Comment: Hi, what is it about the `write` function that you do not understand? If you be more specific with your problem, somebody might be able to provide you with a clear answer.

Comment: What does your book, tutorial or other source of information tell you about the `write` function, especially about its arguments? If you want to write a *single* character, which is a single byte, what arguments do you need to give? Especially, what is the size argument supposed to be?

Comment: Or is the main problem that you get a build error with the code you show? Because it's not valid. Please be specific about the problem you have! Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to *[edit]* your questions to improve them.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=write&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html ... you `write(somewhere, from_this_address, this_number_of_bytes);`. The return value is the effective number of bytes written or `-1` to indicate an error.

Comment: `%ch` seems like a typo for `&ch`. `%ch` causes a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

Write take the output id here you want 1 for default output on terminal
it take a pointer of char, here you have only a char so pass the adress and write will get a pointer of size one char
and last it take the number of char you want to print, here you display them one by one
write do not by default print carriage return

```c
int main()
{
    char ch;

    for(ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
        write(1, &ch, 1);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: by the way this is write ```ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)```